# Extract folder inside large gzip file in windows

Tags: windows, gzip

I have a 200 gb `tar.gz` file I need to extract one folder inside this file. I know exact location of the folder need. Is there any way to do that, any third party tools, or any power shell commands ?

I used WinRar to open the compressed file but it takes long time for indexing the files, because it have lot of KB sized files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unzip partial folder of tar file from url](https://superuser.com/questions/1382258/unzip-partial-folder-of-tar-file-from-url)

Comment: No it is not. I need it in windows and I don't need to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 7-Zip, but it may take a while to open.

Comment: that is the problem because of large amount of small sized files it takes more time  to index the files

Comment: I understand, do you know the name of the file or files you are trying to extract?

Comment: yes, I have the exact location of the folder which I want to extract

Comment: Ok then, the answer to your question is right below this answer. Using 7-Zip in a Command-line. Thank you S. Cloris.

Comment: I tried to extract `myfile.tar.gz` but the out put I got is `myfile.tar`, is there any workaround to get the folder straightly

Comment: I am unfortunately not familiar with command line 7-Zip. However, here is two links to instructions.

Comment: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm

Comment: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:

**Command line for 7z to extract specific files from specific folders inside an archive**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984387/command-line-for-7z-to-extract-specific-files-from-specific-folders-inside-an-ar][1]

Comment: can I extract  `tar.gz` files ?